# Maven install fails with PluginContainerException (DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo)

Tags: maven, swagger

I was trying to setup swagger as mentioned in the link: https://github.com/nacho4d/rest_to_pdf_example

When I run install, it throws the below exception.

```
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------



    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:168)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: A required class was missing while executing io.github.swagger2markup:swagger2markup-maven-plugin:1.0.1:convertSwagger2markup: org/apache/commons/beanutils/DynaBean
```